# How hitting small transformer blacked out whole rio city?

Tags: plot-explanation, rio

In Rio (2011), Parrot hit this transformer thing & it got destroyed.

[image]

& Whole city blacked out

[image]

How destroying small transformer will blacked out whole Rio city ?

Comment: It's animated movie...it's not supposed to *make sense*!